# Buying a 3.5mm TRRS female to TS male adapter

Tags: cable, shopping

I'm trying to buy an adapter from 3.5mm TRRS female to 3.5mm TS male.  I've been searching Google Shopping and Amazon, and not finding anything.

- Do I not know the right keywords?  Can someone help me?
- Does this adapter not exist?
- Is this adapter unnecessary?  Will it just work if you plug in a TRRS to a TS?  I don't have the full hardware yet so I can't test.

**EDIT:** This is for an audio connection.  Stereo+mic TRRS input plugged into a TS mono output.

Comment: Get the hardware first; check the pinout; decide which 2 component wires you wish to discard; make up your own cable.

Comment: What do you actually want to do here. You want to plug the TRRS into something to make it do something? What is it you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a 'TRRS female splitter'. [Random example.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00N03ZYUU)

This splits the TRRS into a TS microphone connector and a TRS headphones connector.

If you want one of the headphones signals available on a mono connector, you need another splitter, these are known as airline headphones adapters. [Random example](https://www.amazon.com/airplane-headphone-adapter-Electronics/s?k=airplane%20headphone%20adapter&rh=n%3A172282).